# In SQL how to not select rows where a column value is the same as the one in the row above it

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with column Value and Timestamp. The values keep coming in per second. So I would have data as follows

```
V1 T1
V1 T2
V2 T3
V3 T4..
```

etc.. So The timestamps would keep increasing, but the values can be the same that they don't change.
I want to select only the rows where the value is different than the previous row.
So I want to reduce the data and select only the records where there is a change in the data. 
Would anybody know how to do this?

Comment: i removed `mysql` tag. correct the tags with the database being used.

Comment: @vkp How did you know which one to remove?

Comment: Window function, LEAD and LAG.

Comment: @Strawberry..I saw sqlserver and t-sql and guessed the chances of it being sql server were higher.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only apply to SQL Server 2012 or later

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        V,T,
        LAG(V) OVER (ORDER BY T) AS LAST_V
    FROM
        TABLE
    )
SELECT
    V, T
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    V <> LAST_V OR LAST_V IS NULL;
```

The LAST_V is the value of V in the previous row, ordered by T. So if V <> LAST_V it means V is not the same as LAST_V which is what was asked. The case LAST_V IS NULL means you are at the first row.

Comment: Wouldn't the 'WHERE' need to be 'LAST_V<>0' implying no change in V between rows implied by the ORDER BY? It would seem V<>LAST_V just includes where a *value* differs from the *delta* - perhaps I'm just not seeing it clearly?

Comment: @DavidW I'm confused. What I meant here is: the LAST_V is the value of V in the previous row, ordered by T. So if V <> LAST_V it means V is not the same as LAST_V which is what was asked. The case LAST_V IS NULL means you are at the first row. Am I missing something?

Comment: @vkp Thanks. I just did (it is practically just the comment I had above).

Comment: Ahh my mistake, @DVT. I was incorrectly reading your solution as returning the *delta* between rows, when clearly it is merely returning the value of the current row. My apologies. You are correct.

Comment: Thankyou!!.A very efficient solution!!

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @YourTable table (Col1 varchar(25),Col2 varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('V1','T1'),
('V1','T2'),
('V2','T3'),
('V3','T4')

;with cteBase as (
    Select *,RowNr=Row_Number() over(Partition By Col1 Order By Col2 Desc) From @YourTable
)
Select * from cteBase where RowNr=1
```

Returns

```
Col1    Col2    RowNr
V1      T2      1
V2      T3      1
V3      T4      1
```

> **OR you can use the With Ties clause**

```
Select Top 1 With Ties *
  From @YourTable
  Order By Row_Number() over(Partition By Col1 Order By Col2 Desc)
```

Returns

```
Col1    Col2
V1      T2  
V2      T3  
V3      T4
```

Comment: i don't think partitioning would work here. You only have to check the value of the previous or the next row against the current row's value.

Comment: @vkp You may very well be correct.  I may have misunderstood the requirements